# Total size of documents in collection2 matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to get the collection1 data which is not present in collection2.

**following is two query which i tried.**

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"collection2",
         let: { "sourcetype": "$field_from_collection_1" },
         pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$field_from_collection_2", "$$sourcetype"] } } },
        ],
         "as":"records_present"
      }
   },
   {
    "$unwind": "$records_present"
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "records_present":{
            "$size":0
         }
      }
   }
]).pretty()
```

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"collection2",
         "localField":"field_from_collection_1",
         "foreignField":"field_from_collection_2",
         "as":"records_present"
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "records_present":{
            "$size":0
         }
      }
   }
], {allowDiskUse: true}).pretty()
```

**which is basically same**

**I have around 1M documents which are present in collection1 but not in collection2**

but running the above query gives me below error.

**Total size of documents in collection2 matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes**

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add a $limit stage at the end of your sub query in your $lookup? I think your case is just checking whether the lookup array is null or not.

Like this:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"collection2",
         let: { "sourcetype": "$field_from_collection_1" },
         pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$field_from_collection_2", "$$sourcetype"] } } },
            { $limit : 1 }
        ],
         "as":"records_present"
      }
   },
   {
    "$unwind": "$records_present"
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "records_present":{
            "$size":0
         }
      }
   }
]).pretty()
```

Another thing is as you $unwind `records_present`, the last $match stage may not give you the expected result as it is not an array field anymore.

Comment: correct unwind will not here since it is returning single document per result not array and **I need to return all the document which are in collection1 and not in collection 2**